# High latency with Web Application Proxy

Tags: exchange-server, adfs, windows-server-2019, exchange-server-2019

Using fresh Windows Server 2019 installs for AD FS, Web Application Proxy and Exchange 2019, I have been getting high (120000ms+) latency loading ECP and any site that requests a large number of files.  Downloading a single file of large size works flawlessly.

Exchange ECP takes nearly two minutes to load and then doesn't work -- the same goes for other complex sites requiring many image/CSS/JS GETs -- see example timing from Firefox:

[image: 2019 WAP high latency]

I have spent many days trying to debug this with numerous reinstalls of AD FS and WAP servers and finding no answer in the MS forums or Googling the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Disable HTTP/2 in IIS manager.

[image]

Such a simple solution.  I hope this can save someone else the days that I have wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Another fix, disable HTTP/2 on WAP server. Add following reg key.

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp\' -Name EnableDefaultHTTP2 -Value 0
```

[Web Application Proxy 2019 - SharePoint 2016 and Office Online Server sites won't load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/8ddf1ed4-5278-42c9-a70e-c1c48aa84e8b)